# CSS Menu Problem

Tags: html, css

my css for the menu

```
     ul#menubar {
     width: 800px;
     padding: 27px 10px 5px 10px;
     list-style: none;
     text-align: center;
     }

    ul#menubar li {
 display: inline;
    }
    ul#menubar li a{
 border-right: 1px solid #111111;
 font: 12px "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Bitstream Vera Sans", "Trebuchet Unicode MS", "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 padding: 5px 10px 8px 10px;
    }

    ul#menubar li a#last {
 border-right: none;
    }

    ul#menubar li a:hover, ul#menubar li a:active{
 background: #8d4d09 url("images/hover.gif") bottom center no-repeat;
 padding-bottom: 8px;
    }
```

menu html

```
    <ul id="menubar">
        <li><a href="#" target="_self">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="_self">Sale</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="_self">Purchase</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="_self">Rent</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="_self">Developments</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="_self">Interior Decorators</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="_self">Maps</a></li>
        <li><a id="last" href="#" target="_self">Legal Documents</a></li>
    </ul>
```

preview
[image: sample]

problem is that i cant figure out the space between the border-right and the anchor  when the link is hovered.

what is causing this space and how can it be removed.

The hovered effect is shown on "Purchase" link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is `display: inline;` - in the source-code you have linebreaks between your li's, wich are represendet as a space on the site (as alwys when you use inline-elements and/or text, see example below).

to avoid this, use `float: left;` or define your ul/li in one line, without spaces/linebreaks between them.

*example:

this sourcecode:

```
this
is
text
```

gives this output:

> this is text

(linebreaks/whitespace are converted to 1 space between words (and the li's are "words" in your case))

Comment: always neglected but important to be noticed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
ul#menubar li {
 display: inline;
 float: left;
}
```

Comment: that has done the trick but creating another problem. I used  text-align: center; to center the anchors <a>. which now appears to be left aligned.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `padding-bottom: 8px` on hover, you already have `padding: 5px 10px 8px 10px;`
 applied to the element. Do you need to set the padding-right on hover too as you will still have 10px applied to it?

Comment: the hover image i am using creates problem if i remove padding-bottom: 8px on hover.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking it could be the browser default style to apply a margin to the left/right of the li. Try setting margins to 0.